C# WPF | Зависимость расстояния между кнопками
Пишу прогу на C# используя WPF, и в ходе задался вопросом, как сделать зависимость расстояния между двумя кнопками, то есть если при наведении курсора на одну кнопку, увеличивается ее размер, а кнопка, которая находится рядом должна сохранить расстояние между двумя этими кнопками, и передвинуться вправо для этого. На данный момент при увеличении первой кнопки, вторая остается на месте, и поэтому первая кнопка просто заползает на нее и перекрывает.
Сразу говорю, сделал чисто для демонстрации наброску стиля и кнопок.

Фотография, когда кнопки в иходном положении:



Фотография, когда курсор наведён на одну из кнопок:


То есть как можно заметить, я навелся на первую кнопку и она "раскрылась", т.е. увеличила размер в ширину, и тем самым заползла на вторую кнопку. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы она не заползала, и вторая кнопка автоматически передвигалась в право, для того чтобы сохранить расстояние между ними
Мой код:
XAML:
<Button Width="32" Height="32" Style="{StaticResource testButtonStyle}" Margin="-80,18,100,0" materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius="13" Padding="6">
    <StackPanel Width="115" Height="32" Margin="-16,-4,0,0">
        <Image Source="/resources/emailIcon.png" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="-63,4,0,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="Настройки" Margin="36,-20,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
<Button Width="32" Height="32" Style="{StaticResource testButtonStyle}" Padding="6" Margin="-90,-32,0,0">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="/resources/emailIcon.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
        <TextBlock Text="Оптимиз" Width="100" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>

Код стиля, прописанный в App.xaml:
<Style x:Key="testButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatMidBgButton}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="#A978FF" Opacity="0.6" ShadowDepth="0" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="115" Duration="0:0:0.2" >
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CircleEase />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="32" Duration="0:0:0.2" >
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CircleEase />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="32" Duration="0:0:0.2" >
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CircleEase />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="32" Duration="0:0:0.2" >
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CircleEase />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


<StackPanel><Button/><Button/></StackPanel>, без всяких Margin="-80,18,100,0" - забудьте про них!!! Научитесь нормально позиционировать объекты. Вот возьмите чистый WPF, не трогая дизайнер и другие UI, чисто в XAML, добавьте кнопку, затем поместите ее в правый угол, потом в нижний левый, нижний правый, затем по центру. Затем добавьте вторую кнопку и сделайте тоже самое, но чтоб первая была по центру, а вторая в нижнем правом углу. Все это без Margin!! Вот когда впитаете эту базовую информацию, тогда таких вопросов вообще не будет.

@EvgeniyZ а как и с помощью чего позиционировать тогда? Мышкой управлять местоположением не даёт стиудия

Я вам ведь говорь "не используйте дизайнер" а вы мне "мышкой не дает"... XAML пишут руками, вот научитесь писать его руками. Он очень простой. За позиционирование отвечают всякие панели по типу Grid, StackPanel, WrapPanel, и т.д. Также за позиционирование отвечают опции выравнивания (VerticalAlignment и HorizontalAlignment). А Margin и Padding - это отступы, они не созданы для того, чтоб кнопка была по центру, их задача немного сместить объект от края другого объекта (скажем, между кнопка вы хотите 10 пикселей отступа). Вот они у вас должны иметь минимальное значение.

Вот допустим, нужна кнопка по центру, вы сейчас делаете что-то такое: <Button Margin ="100 100 0 0"/>, то есть прибиваете гвоздями эту кнопку, не даете ей какой либо свободы. Чуть сдвините окно, поставите другой элемент перед ней, все, у вас все съехало. Правильней будет <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/> - WPF дальше сам поставит куда надо и что надо. Аналогично с двумя объектами, просто оберните в нужную панель и задайте ей нужное выравнивание (<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">..</StackPanel>).

@EvgeniyZ да я так сделал уже, но всё равно динамически положение кнопочки другой при раскрытии и увеличении первой, не изменяется, то есть кнопочка заплывает на другую кнопочку при увеличении. Код такой же как в комментарии выше, только внутри стакпанела находятся кнопки, где Margin слева и справа равен 10

Уберите Width и Height у панели.

"да я так сделал уже...кнопочка заплывает на другую кнопочку" - если вы правильно позиционируете объекты, не ограничиваете их, то такого просто быть не может. Вот вам простой пример, в разметке это просто <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><Button Style="..."/><Button Style="..."/><Button Style="..."/></StackPanel> , а в стиле лишь анимация ширины. Как видите, ничего не заезжает. А знаете когда будет заезжать? Когда я установлю, скажем, 2-й кнопке Margin="-100 0 0 0", тогда да, будет наезд на другую кнопку.
